# Eigenvalue problem with boundary conditions $y(L)=0$, $y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions $y_n(x)$ for the given boundary value problem. (Give your answers in terms of $n$, making sure that each value of $n$ corresponds to a unique eigenvalue.)
>
> $$y'' + \lambda y = 0,  \quad y'(0) = 0, \quad y(L) = 0 $$

I've gone through $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda < 0$, both being trivial.

on $\lambda > 0$, $a = \sqrt{\lambda}$, I end up with $C_1\cos(aL) = 0$ thus

$$ aL = {\pi \over2}, {3\pi \over 2}, {5\pi \over 2} \dots = {2n-1 \over 2} $$

$$\lambda = \left({2n-1\over 2L}\right)^2$$ but this wasn't correct and I'm lost as to why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I also tried setting as just $\lambda  = \left({n\pi \over 2L}\right)^2$ but that still wasn't the correct eigenvalue..

Comment: What do you do there? You have $\cos(aL) = 0$, so $aL\in\{\tfrac{2n+1}{2}\pi : n\in\mathbb Z\}$. Now, divide by $L$ and square.

Comment: Ah, I believe I forgot the pi in there. Woops. Again, its wrong but I the reason lies because of my 2n-1 since in your formula its 2n+1..

Comment: This doesn't make much of a difference. However, in the task they write " making sure that each value of n corresponds to a unique eigenvalue". So you have to be careful because $n\mapsto (\tfrac{2n+1}2)^2$ is not _injective_ on $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ aL = \frac{2n-1}{2}\pi $$

$$ a_n = \frac{2n-1}{2L}\pi $$

$$ \lambda_n = \left( \frac{2n-1}{2L}\pi \right)^2 $$

Note: You can also have 
$$ \lambda_n = \left( \frac{2n+1}{2L}\pi \right)^2 $$
which is the same answer except $n$ starts from $0$ instead of $1$